# Up to date B cell review

Tags: cell-biology, immunology

Where would I find an up to date (last 6-7 years max) review on B cells? I've tried searching through pubmed with filters, cochrane library, medline and various other resources including searching old questions. A textbook would be fine too, but I'm not sure which one would give me detailed information. I'm a BSc student studying immunology. I'm not trying to create a war of "best" answers, any answer that fits these criteria I will accept.

Comment: what specifically about B cells are you interested in? The possible subject matter is so broad that I doubt you'll find reviews covering all of B cell biology and function. A recent immunology text might be better.

Comment: @MattDMo Essentially a standard textbook on immunology level detail but more up to date like novel knowledge on how BCR are activated (for example I read that the cross linking model is widely disputed) etc. Not something that just focuses on the concrete but delves a little further and includes up to date research

Comment: Do you have any references for the BCR cross linking model dispute? I'm not working directly in the field now, so I'm not as up to date as perhaps I should be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cellular and Molecular Immunology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1437715281) by Abul Abbas et al. is pretty good, and you can't beat Charlie Janeway's [Immunobiology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0815342438) either. Both will give a good introduction to B-cells, antibodies, BCR signaling, and how they fit in to the immune system's structure and function. I own earlier editions of both, and their different perspectives are good for getting a more holistic understanding of the field. Good luck in your studies, it's a fascinating subject!

Comment: looking into these! Thanks. And totally agree I love it like anything

Comment: @AndroidPenguin If you're looking for reviews on specific subjects in journals, some of the journals I turn to include Annual Reviews in Immunology, Trends in Biochemical Sciences, Cell, Nature Reviews, Nature Reviews Immunology, and Trends in Immunology, among others. It's quite possible to find great reviews in lower-impact journals like the Journal of Immunology, and you'll often find more esoteric reviews there as well, but for now I'd stick with the real biggies like the ones I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I agree entirely with Matt, [Abbas and Janeway](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK27142/)'s books are the standard for even graduate-level introductory Immunology. Both are easy to read and well organized. Definitely start here.

However, depending on what you have access to and the depth of reading you want to do, there was an *Annual Review of Immunology* issue some years ago (maybe 2003?) that discussed a number of B Cell topics (signaling, fate decisions, etc). I also see that there is a newer article: 
["B Cell Signaling and Fate Decision"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19827951)
*Annual Review of Immunology* 28: 21-55 (Volume publication date April 2009)
Tomohiro Kurosaki, Hisaaki Shinohara, and Yoshihiro Baba
that might be pretty general if you have access through a university.

Good luck.

By the way, I think the disagreement about BCR crosslinking is for survival/development (i.e., are '[tonic' signals](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16557260) sufficient to allow cells through development?) As for activation, B cells are triggered either by antigen-specific BCR crosslinking or more general [TLR activation](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23241902) (e.g., LPS).

Comment: could you post Pubmed/DOI links so others can find the article you're referencing? They're more likely to be "permanent" (long-lasting) than are direct journal URLs, which can and do change.

Comment: Good point. Done.